# package mlmodern with lualatex changes single quote in listings to backquote. How to fix this?

Tags: fonts, listings, mlmodern

I like to use `\usepackage{mlmodern}` but I noticed it changes `'` in listings. Is there to tell it not to do this? I use lualatex.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]
DSolve[y'[x]==(x+y[x])^(1/2),y[x],x]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output PDF shows this

[image]

Compiling without `mlmodern` gives

[image]

The problem with the first version is that now one can't copy and paste the code as is, since it is no longer valid. It should remain `'` and not backquote

TL 2022 on Linux.

**Update:**

Same issue happens with pdflatex. But with pdflatex with and without `mlmodern` it changes to backquote.

Comment: There is no OpenType version of MLModern, so using LuaLaTeX is not really a choice.

Comment: @egreg I've been using it with lualatex for a year now, and had no problem at all. Except for this minor issue with lisiting and quote character.  In addition, same problem happens with pdflatex. (but noticed with pdflatex it is always backquote which is even more strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the manual can help.

[image]

Actually the reference to `textcomp` is outdated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{upquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]
DSolve[y'[x]==(x+y[x])^(1/2),y[x],x]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't recommend using LuaLaTeX as is with fonts not in OpenType format. Also, terminology is wrong: there is no back quote in your output, but rather a *closing quote* `’`.

By the way, this is the output I get without `mlmodern` and not setting `upquote`, using LuaLaTeX:

[image]

So there's something you didn't tell.

Comment: Thanks. I did google this and could not find this option for listings ref the quote.

Comment: @Nasser I opened `texdoc listings` and looked for “quote”.

Comment: You are much smarter than me.